# Android :How to animate the speedometer needle

Tags: java, android

I implemented the speedometer in my project by referring the code as found in the below link.

I need to animate the speedometer needle till i get the result from server, and once i got the result , i need to set the needle to proper value based on some calculation.

I am not understanding how to do it.

Please help me with some solution.

https://github.com/ntoskrnl/SpeedometerView/blob/master/CardioMoodSpeedometerView/SpeedometerView/src/main/java/com/cardiomood/android/speedometer/SpeedometerView.java

Comment: What code do you have so far, where are the problems in it. And maybe a screenshot with it to see what is wrong could be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private SpeedometerView speedometer;

// Customize SpeedometerView
speedometer = (SpeedometerView) v.findViewById(R.id.speedometer);

// Add label converter
speedometer.setLabelConverter(new SpeedometerView.LabelConverter() {
  @Override
  public String getLabelFor(double progress, double maxProgress) {
      return String.valueOf((int) Math.round(progress));
  }
});

// configure value range and ticks
speedometer.setMaxSpeed(300);
speedometer.setMajorTickStep(30);
speedometer.setMinorTicks(2);

// Configure value range colors
speedometer.addColoredRange(30, 140, Color.GREEN);
speedometer.addColoredRange(140, 180, Color.YELLOW);
speedometer.addColoredRange(180, 400, Color.RED);
```

Check the readme. Here you will find above code. And i think you need to look for how to change the needle.

And then call the public method SetSpeed(double speed) on the speedometer object.
A simple look through the code in your link provides the answer.

Comment: I am using this library but my speedometer does not shows any label over the MajorTicks. I'm using your code by MaxSpeed is 100